# How to programmatically add options to list_text field

Tags: 7, users

I want to programmatically add a drop down list field to the user profile via a custom module. How do I go about adding select options for the field?

```
// Create Field
'suffix' => array(
  'field_name' => 'suffix',
  'type' => 'list_text',
),

//Create instance
'suffix' => array(
  'field_name' => 'suffix',
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'label' => 'Suffix',
  'bundle' => 'user',
  'options' => array(
   '0' => 'Mr.',
   '1' => 'Mrs.',
  ),
  'widget' => array(
  'type' => 'list_text',
  );
),
```

The field shows up but the options do not. Anyone have a good guide they know of or tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Where are your `field_create_field()` and `field_create_instance()`? These are just two arrays that have no specific meaning. Please post full code, not just arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Your available widgets for a list field are these: `options_select`, `options_buttons` and `options_onoff`, not `list_text`, that is the field type.

The widget values can be found on [`list_field_widget_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_field_widget_info_alter/7.x), where the list types are coupled with the widgets.

So I suppose you should update your field instance to use:

```
'widget' => array(
  'type' => 'options_select', // Drop down button or multi-select
  // OR 
  // 'type' => 'options_buttons', // Radio buttons or checkboxes.
);
```

The way the widget is rendered depends on the `cardinality` defined on your field. If cardinality is set to 1, the first type will be used (drop down or radio buttons), if cardinality > 1, you'll get a multi-select field or checkboxes.

Assuming this field can only hold one value, you should also add

```
'cardinality' => 1,
```

To your field definition.

Leaving you with:

```
// Create Field
$field = array(
  'suffix' => array(
    'field_name' => 'suffix',
    'type' => 'list_text',
    'cardinality' => 1,
  ),
);
field_create_field($field);


//Create instance
$instance = array(
  'suffix' => array(
    'field_name' => 'suffix',
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'label' => 'Suffix',
    'bundle' => 'user',
    'options' => array(
     '0' => 'Mr.',
     '1' => 'Mrs.',
    ),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'options_select',
    ),
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

Comment: #Neograph734 All source code is in  list_field_widget_info_alter()